# Problem with kernel header files for installing VirtualBox on Debian 10

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtualbox on Debian 10. But when I run `# /sbin/vboxconfig` I get the following error message:

> This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
> Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
> for adding new hardware support to the system.
> The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
> linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.19.0-13-amd64

But `# apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` leads to

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.0-13-amd64
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.0-13-amd64'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.0-13-amd64'

It is a fresh install of Debian 10. Output of `uname -a` is `Linux c2 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Any ideas what I am missing? How do I install the correct headers so that `vboxconfig` is happy?

Kind Regards,

Comment: probably up-to-date  https://packages.debian.org/buster/linux-image-amd64 (and a reboot)

Comment: The [most recent kernel headers in Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/linux-headers-amd64) are at a slightly newer revision 4.19.0-16. Pethaps an `apt upgrade` helps?

Comment: I did apt update before trying to install virtualbox. and thanks to the person who closed this question, I did ask it because I did not find anything that solves my problem. goodbye stackexchange...